# PropertyChangedCallback on DependencyProperty Only Firing Once

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

I have the exact problem as this [guy in the Silverlight Forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/57516/499086.aspx) and the accepted answer is :

> In this case, your property didn't actually change value.  You added
>   something to your List, but the list is the same List so when the
>   DependencyProperty mechanism sees that the actual value (reference to
>   your List) didn't change, it didn't raise your OnChanged handler

This is a great explication but not an answer to fix this problem. I can find on Google many suggestion for WPF but not for Silverlight.

The problem is describe as this one : You have a DependencyProperty that is called when the variable is initialized but after then nothing is updated.

```
public partial class MyGrid : UserControl
{
    public MyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Shapes", typeof(ObservableCollection<ModelItem>), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(OnShapesPropertyChanged));

    public ObservableCollection<ModelItem> Shapes
    {
        private get { return (ObservableCollection<ModelItem>)GetValue(ShapesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShapesProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnShapesPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyGrid)o).OnShapesPropertyChanged(e); //Fire Only Once
    }

    private void OnShapesPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg.ItemsSource = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<ModelItem>;
    }


}

//--------
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand cmd;
    public ObservableCollection<ModelItem> ModelItemCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return  Model.ModelItem;
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Model = new Model();
        Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelItemCollection"));
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCmd
    {
        get { return cmd ?? (cmd = new RelayCommand(a => Model.ModelItem.Add(new ModelItem {Name = "asd"}))); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

///----------------------

public class Model: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ModelItem> ModelItem { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        ModelItem = new ObservableCollection<ModelItem>();
        ModelItem.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ModelItem_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void ModelItem_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelItem"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class ModelItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Even with explicit call of PropertyChanged() nothing is updated.

What is the workaround to let know the DependencyProperty that the ObservableCollection has elements that have changed?

Comment: I think what you're seeing here is due to a confusion as to the use of ObservableCollection. You're not seeing a property changed event because the ObservableCollection itself isn't being changed once you have initialized it, rather you're going to be adding or removing elements *within* the ObservableCollection. So the property (that is an ObservableCollection) isn't changing itself, and wont raise an event. But if you bind to the ObservableCollection (for an ItemSource or something) you should get changes when you add or remove items from the collection. Am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: I can without problem add item and see it display on the screen. My problem concern only the fact that the DependencyProperty is not fired and than the value not set. This is why in the Model_PropertyChanged I added explicitly PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelItemCollection") so when a item is added, this method (Model_PropertyChanged) is fired but still : i want the ModelItemCollection to "rebind". This is not happening.

Comment: did you ever try to use UpdateTarget() ?

Comment: @Daok Ah, I see. Then I believe you should follow Tigran's advice and try UpdateTarget, [here is an example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/68dec4fa-7ea1-4fb5-8785-ed279ee3d69f/wpf-explicitly-update-binding-source-or-target.aspx) so you can see how to implement it.

Comment: From which object? Can you be more accurate please and I'll try.

Comment: Okay but the ViewModel that contain the collection does not have the View Control. It uses Binding to interact with the View.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(dependencyObject, dependencyProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Look here: [forcing a WPF binding to 'refresh' ...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/04/forcing-a-wpf-binding-to-refresh.aspx)

Try this, usually works :)

Comment: I still need something to notify the View that the Model has changed. This call can only be done on the View side because it requires to have a reference on the object and property.

Comment: @Daok this *does* update the View. This call notifies any targets that have bound to the source dependency property that they need to update to pick up new information

Comment: dependencyObject and dependencyProperty are both in the View. Forgive me my ignorance but how can I call BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase with 2 things that I have no access (changes are done Model side)?

Comment: @Daok: correct the chnages are made in Model side, but you have (I hope) ModelView, which have to be a bridge between Model and View. Put that code inside ModelView scope.

Comment: Yes I have a ModelView but this one is not aware of what is the View it just provide Property that the View will bind to it...